# iPhone localization - some localized XIBs do not load

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization

I have made an iPhone app with localized versions. It mostly works fine, but there are two views in which localized NIBs do not load. Standard NIBs (in English) are used. I am sure I made localization properly ("Get Info", "Make file localizable", "Add Localization", added "pl" - for Polish, and then edited created NIB). All the other views are fine. What might be the problem?

Comment: Interesting thing. It works fine on the simulator, not properly on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is: reboot the iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

Another one for the simulator on SDK 4.0 - delete the application on the simulator, build -> clean all targets in XCode and restart

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on the Simulator. Cleaning all targets helped me. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

On the simulator I had to use "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings"