# localized nib not working in a iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, internationalization, interface-builder

I am working on an iPhone project which I have translated to two languages : French and Spanish.

The issue I have is just with one file : the RootViewController nib.

I localized the MainWindow.nib, and it works (when I change the language, the text in the app changes according to what I specified). I also have several NSLocalizedStrings, with a Localizable.strings file, which also works, but this RootViewController doesn't:

I made the file localizable, added two languages (fr and es), which I modified, the files are located in the fr.lproj folder and es.lproj folder, and they are included in the Target/App/"Copy Bundle Ressources".
The text in the app is always the one from the English nib, even when I change the language.

Any idea where this would come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is your English xib in the en.lproj folder side by side with the other languages?  If your english xib is in the root, it may just be finding that and not looking elsewhere.

Comment: That's great, it worked on the iPhone simulator, but it still doesn't work on my device. What does it mean ? The "clean target" thing is not possible on device, is it ?

Comment: Clean builds are available for the device as well as the simulator. Additionally, you should delete the app from your device and reinstall (after doing a clean build) to see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, it works. I may award the bounty in 5 hours. It will be done. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've got the exact same problem, but with English & Spanish

The answer is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2895488/225503). 
I've just [cleaned all targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895488/iphone-localization-some-localized-xibs-do-not-load/3797075#3797075) and all is fine now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know the return key would send the comment! So I cleaned the target on the simulator, deleted the app, it didn't change. It also doesn't work on the device.